# Java EE @Resource annotation, lookup, NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, resources, annotations

I am studying a book called Beginning Java EE 7, but I failed running one of the examples from the book. When I run the code below, the output is:

Infinite loop. Waiting for a message...

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at org.agoncal.book.javaee7.chapter13.ex05.Consumer05.main(Consumer05.java:34)

I have used an if statement to check objects "connectionFactory" and "queue" and I found out that they are both null. Does anyone know how to fix this error?

The source code can be found here: https://github.com/agoncal/agoncal-book-javaee7

chapter 13, chapter13-samples.

```
package org.agoncal.book.javaee7.chapter13.ex05;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.JMSContext;
import javax.jms.Queue;

/**
 * @author Antonio Goncalves
 *         APress Book - Beginning Java EE 7 with Glassfish 4
 *         http://www.apress.com/
 *         http://www.antoniogoncalves.org
 *         --
 */
public class Consumer05 {

  // ======================================
  // =             Attributes             =
  // ======================================

  @Resource(lookup = "jms/javaee7/ConnectionFactory")
  private static ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
  @Resource(lookup = "jms/javaee7/Queue")
  private static Queue queue;

  // ======================================
  // =           Public Methods           =
  // ======================================

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Loops to receive the messages
    System.out.println("\nInfinite loop. Waiting for a message...");
    try (JMSContext context = connectionFactory.createContext()) {
      while (true) {
        String message = context.createConsumer(queue).receiveBody(String.class);
        System.out.println("Message received: " + message);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: My guess is that you are running the program as a regular Java program.  `@Resource` doesn't do anything special by itself, such as setting the `connectionFactory` field's value;  it is simply a marker that is recognized by Java EE containers, and it is those containers which set a field's value.  You must run your program as a Java EE application client and not just as a regular program.

Comment: Thank you @VGR, that was the problem. I created a new Java EE project(Enterprise Application Client) and created the same class in that project, it worked!